# Custom variables in Devise reset password instructions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailer, password-recovery

I need to be able to customise the rails devise mailer view for reset password instructions.

for this I need to do two things.

1. Specify a custom URL for the link, so that its a host/domain based on a certain business logic. This host and domain comes from the URL in the browser, i.e. the request object, when the user clicks forgot password. So I do not have the request object in delayed_job to process it as I need, hence I need to be able to do this at some point in the delayed_job that is sending the email.
2. Pass custom variables to the mailer view, so that I can add in various other logic for the view, hiding and showing bits as I need.

Can anyone help? I can see that you can generate the mailer views for devise, but I need to be able pass over various items to it also. Do I need to somehow override the functions myself in my User model and password controller for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, after much ado and searching and hacking around with stuff... this is just not possible. so I ended up writing my own mailer and bypassing the devise reset password methods in the controllers, to generate my own reset token, set my variables I needed, called my usermailer.... and embedded the devise url in my mail to get it back calling devise once the password reset link was clicked, and all was fine then....

I hated having to rewrite the logic, but in the end its the quickest and cleanest solution.

One approach that nearly worked, was using a non activerecord attribute on my user model to store the bits I needed and "hacking" that into the @resource in the devise view, but it was causing some grief in devise doing so, as a result, I went with the option above...

Answer (score 4):

Overriding the whole controller method and adding param in `send_reset_password_instructions` opts parameters will fix it.

```
@resource.send_reset_password_instructions(
    email: @email,
    provider: 'email',
    redirect_url: @redirect_url,
    client_config: params[:config_name],
    parameter_passed: params[:parameter_passed],
  )
```

You can access the param in the view as `message['parameter_passed']`

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this too before I realized that declaring custom variables BEFORE calling super will work.

```
  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
   @custom_variable = "Greetings, world"

    # your gorgeous code

   mailer_object = super

   mailer_object
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add a `source` to be included into the reset password view, here's what I implemented:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  prepend ResetPasswordWithSource

  devise :recoverable

  ....
end

module User::ResetPasswordWithSource
  def send_reset_password_instructions(source=nil)
    @source = source
    super()
  end

  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    args.last.merge!({ source: @source })
    super
  end
end
```

From here you can just call `user.send_reset_password_instructions('special_source')`

And can access in views via `@options[:source] = 'special_source'`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `flag` to display in the view mailer. From here you can just call a method and pass the parameter.

```
@user.send_reset_password_instructions("true")
```

Now override the method send_reset_password_instructions

```
def send_reset_password_instructions(option = nil)
  token = set_reset_password_token
  send_reset_password_instructions_notification(token, option)
  token 
end

def send_reset_password_instructions_notification(token, option = nil)
  send_devise_notification(:reset_password_instructions, token, :option => option)
end
```

Then you can access the parameter by using:

```
message[:option]
```